# What is lazy evaluation in functional programming language? And how it helps?

Tags: apache-spark, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I just read the concept of lazy evaluation, but could not understand. Can someone offer an explanation?

Comment: There are many places where lazy evaluation is explained in detail. Which one did you read, and which part *specifically* do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: Lazy understanding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It saves resources. You can for example have an infinite array (which wouldn't fit into memory) and you generate each of its values only when they are actually being read.

Also check out http://perldesignpatterns.com/?LazyEvaluation